# jQuery script and drop down lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a very strange problem, on my site I have a list that according to the user choice updates the values in another list :

```
<form id="form1">
        <div>
            <select id="workField">
                <option value="HI-TEC">HI-TEC</option>
                <option value="Food Industry">Food Industry</option>
                <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
            </select>
            <select id="occupetion">
                <option value="QA">QA</option>
                <option value="Food Industry">Food inspectur</option>
                <option value="Marketing">Selles man</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <script>
            $("#workField").change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == "HI-TEC") {
                    $("#occupetion").val("QA");
                }
                if ($(this).val() == "Food Industry") {
                    $("#occupetion").val("Food Industry");
                }
                if ($(this).val() == "Marketing") {
                    $("#occupetion").val("Marketing");
                }
            });
        </script>
    </form>
```

as I add the jQuery links :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js">
```

It stops working. Any suggestions? I still want to keep the jQuery style.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/dwxmjkb3/9/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have created jsfiddle for you..

code:-

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

working example:-
http://jsfiddle.net/dwxmjkb3/8/

i think you were missing `</script>`  from the code see this..

thanks

Comment: it works fine until i had the jqurey links , still didnt fix that problem . but thanks!

Comment: jsfiddle is not working for you?

Comment: work but like i said , there is a problem with jquery links :<head>
   <script src="jsCode.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jtheme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet"href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js">
</script>

Comment: can you paste your code into jsfiddle and show me your problem..please remove the semicolons from the script and link rags and also provide the space before href in html thanks

Comment: i think i got it , thank u , i had 2 links that don't work together !thank u!!

Comment: how do i vote here? new to stackoverflow

Comment: vote up require 15 + rep ...

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested it and it's working fine, try putting the scripts in the head tag and use $(document).ready(), and check if there is any errors caused by other scripts in your browser's console.

```
<head>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#workField").change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == "HI-TEC") {
                    $("#occupetion").val("QA");
                }
                if ($(this).val() == "Food Industry") {
                    $("#occupetion").val("Food Industry");
                }
                if ($(this).val() == "Marketing") {
                    $("#occupetion").val("Marketing");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have things in order, i have just tested out your code and it seems to be working fine.

So Stylesheet first declared on the page, then the jquery (in the head). Followed by the code in in the body.

Also, you havent declared a whether you want it when the window is ready or loadng.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
            $("#workField").change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == "HI-TEC") {
                    $("#occupetion").val("QA");
                }
                if ($(this).val() == "Food Industry") {
                    $("#occupetion").val("Food Industry");
                }
                if ($(this).val() == "Marketing") {
                    $("#occupetion").val("Marketing");
                }
            });
});//]]>  

</script>
```

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/9bd4tg75/

Comment: sory but still it doesn't work when i use jqurey links , the js code is fine , same as the structure .

Answer (score 0):

please add this in head section.

```
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#workField").change(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == "HI-TEC") {
                    $("#occupetion").val("QA");
                }
                if ($(this).val() == "Food Industry") {
                    $("#occupetion").val("Food Industry");
                }
                if ($(this).val() == "Marketing") {
                    $("#occupetion").val("Marketing");
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: tried and the problem isnt that , its start when im adding the jqurey links .

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work for me until I change:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js">
```

to:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

This mistake is apparent if you use a text editor with syntax checking or syntax highlighting.

---

Comment: no that's not the problem , i didn't copy paste that right.

Comment: Your question should be updated to prevent other users from making this mistake.